# access query that returns records for previous year up to same day, same month as today but for previous year

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need help specifying an access criteria on a date field that would pull records from my database from the beginning of last year, 1/1/2014 to a date that has the same day, and same month as today. The reason for this information is to be able to able to compare year-to-date records(and later counts) for this year to year-to-date's count for last year... thus, if today's date is 8/20/2015, I would want to be able to pull from 1/1/2015 to 8/20/2015 and then compare it to 1/1/2014 to 8/20/2014. 
Just for heads-up, I am using the same query and form to count records based on weekly, quarterly date-ranges, and so I cannot use textboxes with "Start" and "End" dates. Also, I cannot pre-specify any date in my query.  Any idea will be greatly appreciated. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get last year's year-to-date `DateSerial` will do what you want.

```
Where [DateColumn] >= DateSerial(year(now)-1,1,1) 
      and [DateColumn] <= DateSerial(year(now)-1,month(now),day(now))
```

Another option

```
Where [DateColumn] >= dateadd("yyyy", datediff("yyyy", 0, now)-2, 2 )
      and [DateColumn <= DateAdd("yyyy",-1, now)
```

Comment: @Gustav, What environment are you in where `Now` doesn't work? `Date` and now are both in the `DateTime` module. I'd expect if one works the other one will too.

Comment: thanks @Brad. Both approaches work for me. Thank you

Comment: @Brad: A query - as the questioneer stated.

Comment: @Gustav that's curious. When you do `Select now` in the query designer and run it what does it tell you?

Comment: You are correct. `Now` works as is. However, neither `Date` nor `Time` do. Thus, as well I've always used `Now()` in SQL. I always use `Date` and `Date()` when time is not needed - like here.

Comment: @Gustav I see what you mean. very odd. I wouldn't expect any of them to need `()` because they are all properties and not subs or functions. oh well.

Comment: The difference may be that `Date` and `Time` in fact equal the old DOS commands and settings. This means they also work the other way: `Date = #7/6/2000#` and `Time = #5:40#` actually would set the date and time in old (pre NT) Windows versions. Today, trying this results in an "Access denied" error. Different from these, `Now` was invented with Access Basic and VB for a convenient way to set date and time in one go.

Comment: @Gustav that'd be interesting. `Now` is the only one of them marked as `Read-only` so that follows.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Date() in SQL:

```
Where [DateColumn] >= DateSerial(Year(Date())-1,1,1) 
      And [DateColumn] <= DateAdd("yyyy",-1,Date())
```

Comment: Thanks @Gustav. Your approach works for me as well. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The following expression can be used as the criteria for the date field in the query designer

```
>="01/01/" & (Year(Date())-1) AND <=Day(Date()) & "/" & Month(Date()) & "/" & Year(Date())-1
```

**Warning:** using strings to build dates should be avoided when possible.  DateSerial() is a better approach, but this will work in MS Access (Jet/ACE).

Comment: You should never use string handling for dates - and dd/mm/yyyy will fail in SQL.

Comment: agree; using strings to build dates is not a best practice and should be avoided when possible...DateSerial() in this case.  The OP indicated "Any idea will be greatly appreciated."  and this answer does provide the desired results...

Comment: I could work, but it will fail for date values between 1 and 12 because SQL will read the dd/mm/yyyy string as mm/dd/yyyy. Always use the yyyy-mm-dd format.